# Sentence ending in かも・・・ what is the meaning?

Tags: meaning, sentence-final-particles

I am translating a guidebook for a Legend of Zelda game, for study purposes. I'm finding a variety of new phrases and words, but this one has me stumped.

This is in the introduction to a section 冒険のヒント (Adventure Hints):

> 冒険の途中で困ったときに思い出してほしい。  At the time when you’re worried in the middle of the adventure [you will] wish to remember [these hints & advice].
>
> 解決の糸口になるかも・・・    ???????????????????????

It must mean something like "the resolution to this might be beginning below" but that is just my guess. Could somebody help me out with an explanation please?

Comment: Related (about 〜てほしい in the first sentence, not your actual question): http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15686/1478

Answer (score 7, accepted):

かも is short for かも知れない【しれない】, which loosely translates as "probably".  In this case, "It **might well be** the beginning of a solution," would be a good translation.

Comment: Ah. Although Rikaichan and alc.co.jp don't help me translate this, I found this example on a Japanese site
明日雨かもしれない - tomorrow it might well rain

Comment: Maybe is more common translation than "might well be", which to my ears suggests a higher degree of probability (than maybe).